# TFS 2015 - Can't create data set in new report from remote machine

Tags: sql-server, tfs, tfs-2015

I'm using TFS 2015 Update 1, with SQL Server Analysis Services enabled, and I'm trying to use Report Builder (launched from Internet Explorer) to create custom reports.

I'm trying to create a new report using the existing Data Source Connections (Tfs2010ReportDS and Tfs2010OlapReportDS) from a different machine to the one running SQL Server/SQL Server Analysis Services. The steps I have taken are as follows:

1. Launch table wizard
2. Select "Create a dataset"
3. Click "Next"
4. Click on Tfs2010OlapReportDS datasource
5. Click "Next".

I am then asked to enter data source credentials [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of8ko.png)

When I enter the credentials of the TFS Reader account (TFSReports) I am told the connection failed due to an incorrect username or password. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJBon.png)

This operation succeeds when carried on on the machine running SQL Server, and I know its not the firewall as I can connect from Excel and also taking down the firewall briefly makes no difference.

Any ideas how I can resolve?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you’re using an account you created in SQL Server, you would simply enter in the user name, and not check the “Use as Windows credentials” option.

If you’re using an Active directory account, You’ll need to check the “Use as Windows credentials”.

Comment: I'm using Windows accounts, not SQL Server accounts. No AD as its an experimental server...And as I said, the exact same procedure works when I remote desktop into the machine running SQL server, but not when I connect from another machine.

Comment: I just tried a Windows account, and could reproduce your issue. As an alternative, you can use a AD account instead of Windows Account. Meanwhile, submit a feedback at website http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio